# Is total mechanical energy always equal to maximum potential energy?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Am I correct in stating this: When initial velocity of an object is $0$ then the total mechanical energy will *always* be equal to the maximum potential energy (with maximum height or displacement) (Free fall, spring, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not always true.

According to conservation of energy, the change in total mechanical energy of a system is determined by the work done by forces external to the system:
$$\Delta E=\Delta K+\Delta U=W_\text{ext}$$

What you are proposing is true if $W_\text{ext}=0$, because then as $\Delta K\geq0$ it must be that $\Delta U\leq0$. Since we started with $E=U$, it must be that the total mechanical energy is constant and equal to this maximum potential energy value.

However, if $W_\text{ext}\neq0$, then this no longer applies. For example, we can have an external force do work on the system to increase the kinetic energy without changing the potential energy. At this point then the mechanical energy will be greater than the maximum potential energy.

Therefore, your claim is only valid when there are no external forces doing work on your system. (These are non-conservative forces or any conservative force you have not taken into account in $\Delta U$).